# nodejs session stores only json?

Tags: node.js, session, sequelize.js

I have a logged in user object that i shove into my session. The user object is a sequelize user object instance, it has many useful methods on it.

When i read the object back from session, all i have now is a json representation of my object. All the useful methods are gone.

**Node Question:** Is it possible to put full object into the session, not just the json representations?

**Sequelize Question:** Having a json representation of an object, is it possible to construct a full sequelize object without having to requery?

Comment: Do you remember the outcome of this @mkoryak? What's the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate object functions and data, for example:

```
user.prototype.methods = userMethods;
user.prototype.data = req.session.userData

function userMethods(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of session are we talking about?

1. For cookie sessions: Serializing everything will make the client's headers massive (slow / large requests) and will burden your server more with every request.
2. For database-backed sessions: You store a small session-id in the cookie, then you have to query the Database for the session object in any case.

   Use that query to get the complete user object instead, by saving the user-id in the cookie and not the session-id.

Last option:

1. Figure out how to instantiate a user object from the data in `sequelize`. I haven't used that ORM, but the other ORM stuff I've used (mongoose) lets you instantiate an object back from its data, which will give you access to all the useful methods you're missing again.

EDIT: From the docs, I'm thinking that you can get the JSON that was saved in your session (`session.user`), then restore a user instance like this:

```
var restoredUserInstance = MyUserModel.build(session.user);
```

Since your user model's JSON will probably include your primary key (email or username or something), you can then use  `restoredUserInstance.save()` and all the other methods as expected (save will update, etc.) Let me know if that doesn't work and we can dig further into the docs/code.

I had a look and found the following explanation of how to instantiate an instance from JSON without calling a DB `find()`: https://github.com/sdepold/sequelize/issues/191

Comment: last option is what i need. ill look into it